# Ubuntu is shutting down while inactive

Tags: shutdown

After upgrading to 17.10, Ubuntu is shutting down itself while inactive for a long time. My settings are only to suspend while inactive. As per this setting, Ubuntu will suspend while inactive. But after that, it shutdowns after some time.
This happens only when running on battery power, but not due to battery drain out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During suspend, there is far from negligible battery use so the computer will still shut down after a while. For some reason, that is the case even without a full battery drain-out; sometimes I can power it back on and confirm like 1% before starting charging.